# python - remove quotes and brackets when printing a list of lists into a file

Tags: python, list, text-files

my list looks like this

```
[['1', 'book1', 'dffd'], ['2', 'book2', 'dsd']]
```

How would i store it in a text file so it looks like this

```
1,book1,dffd
2,book2,dsd
```

- 

```
textfile = open("books2.txt", "w")
for element in booksdata:
    textfile.write (str(element))
textfile.close()
```

Comment: Learn/use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex on the sublists once converted to string.

```
with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in test:
        str_item = str(item)
        str_item_cleaned = re.sub(r"[[\[\]\'\" ]","",str_item)
        f.write(str_item_cleaned + "\n")
```

This has provided me with a txt file that looks as your intended output shows:

```
1,book1,dffd
2,book2,dsd
```

To explain the process, the sublists are being iterated through, converted to strings, then any of the undesired symbols are being removed with regex, and then that cleaned up data is being written to the txt file along with a new line at the end for each sublist.